# How to reorder a column in a data frame to be the last column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where columns are constantly being added to it.  I also have a total column that I would like to stay at the end.  I think I must have skipped over some really basic command somewhere but cannot seem to find the answer anywhere.  Anyway, here is some sample data:

```
x=1:10
y=21:30
z=data.frame(x,y)
z$total=z$x+z$y
z$w=11:20
z$total=z$x+z$y+z$w
```

When I type `z` I get this:

```
    x  y total  w
1   1 21    33 11
2   2 22    36 12
3   3 23    39 13
4   4 24    42 14
5   5 25    45 15
6   6 26    48 16
7   7 27    51 17
8   8 28    54 18
9   9 29    57 19
10 10 30    60 20
```

Note how the total column comes before the w, and obviously any subsequent columns.  Is there a way I can force it to be the last column?  I am guessing that I would have to use `ncol(z)` somehow.  Or maybe not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reorder your columns as follows:

```
z <- z[,c('x','y','w','total')]
```

To do this programmatically, after you're done adding your columns, you can retrieve their names like so:

```
nms <- colnames(z)
```

Then you can grab the ones that aren't 'total' like so:

```
nms[nms!='total']
```

Combined with the above:

```
z <- z[, c(nms[nms!='total'],'total')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a logic issue here.  Whenever you add to a data.frame, it grows to the right.

Easiest fix: keep total a vector until you are done, and only then append it. It will then be the rightmost column.

(For critical applications, you would of course determine your width `k` beforehand, allocate `k+1` columns and just index the last one for totals.)